# Redirect file drop event into file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I'm working on a basic jQuery plugin that attaches itself to a file input and allows the user to choose an image, with which the plugin will then generate a preview.

**Note:** The plugin doesn't immediately try to upload the file (That will happen when a form is submitted and is beyond the scope of the plugin).

What want to do is accept a `drop` event on another element (In this case the `window`), which would ideally set the value of the file input to be the dropped file, and update the preview.

Now I know from researching and looking at other questions similar to this, that it's not possible to programmatically set the value of a file input for security reasons, which makes perfect sense. User action is required to set the value of the file input.

- Is there some way to perhaps take something from the `drop` event (Which is user input) and use it to fill the file input's value? Or is it just simply not possible whatsoever to programmatically set it's value?
- Alternatively, if the above isn't possible - is there perhaps a way to redirect the drop event from my other element, onto the file input and let the browser handle setting the file input's value?

The only other way I could conceive this working would be to have the file input (Which in my case is positioned off-screen) follow the mouse around while it's dragging so that the `drop` event eventuallylands in the file input.

Any other techniques or tips welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I do a technique for customize the file inputs that could help you in this case. You have to scale by CSS the file input to the screen size and then give it an opacity of `0` to make it invisible to the user. By this way you don't have to track any drag n drop. In the case that you want to allow the user to make more thing in the window then you could track the drag event to set the input to that styles config and forget about follow the cursor.

Comment: Nice technique, I'll give that a shot, thanks

Comment: Did it worked? @Jonathon

Comment: It didn't work with the time I dedicated to it unfortunately. I'm sure I could have got something working with that technique though, it was promising. I just decided against spending more time getting it working and moved onto other things. Thanks for your suggestion though :)

Comment: @AlbertoFdzM Nice trick . Something like this: `input[type="file"] {
 border: thin solid red; /* for testing only */
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
}`